# Why are spanning trees called spanning trees?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, trees

My question is about terminology.

I am interested in the reason why spanning trees are called this way. English is not my native language so maybe there is something that I don't see and a native speaker would see.

Why are spanning trees of a graph called like this "spanning" ?

Comment: A "spanning subgraph" of a graph $G$ is a subgraph $H$ of $G$ which has the save vertex set, $V(H)=V(G).$ (I don't know why it's called a "spanning" subgraph.) In particular, a "spanning tree" is a spanning subgraph which is a tree, a "spanning path" is a spanning subgraph which is a path.

Comment: @bof thanks. I did not know about spanning graphs

Comment: The term is *spanning subgraph*, not spanning graph. Here is a [wikipedia referene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#S) for this terminology.

Answer (score 4):

In mathematics, the word "span" is used about one thing that can reach every part of a (possibly) larger thing, under a suitable definition of "reach". A tree is a special kind of graph. So a spanning tree of a given graph is a smaller graph (a so-called *subgraph*) which reaches every node of the original graph, but at the same time fulfills the requirements of a tree.